# Где хранить логин и пароль при тестировании авторизации в системе

Tags: php, codeception

Использую [Codeception](http://codeception.com/) для выполнения приемочного тестирования. Для проверки входа в систему есть вот такой тестовый сценарий:

```
<?php

$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->amOnPage('/login');
$I->fillField('Login', '<login>')
$I->fillField('Password', '<password>');
$I->click('Login');
$I->see('You are now logged in!');
```

Есть ли какой-то конфиг, куда можно вынести пару "логин/пароль" (для входа в целевую систему), чтобы не прописывать ее в каждом сценарии, требующим авторизации?

Возможно есть способ как-то использовать конфигурационный файл самого Codeception для хранения в нем произвольных параметров?

Comment: А просто в какой-нибудь конфиг писать и читать на этапе подготовки теста нельзя? В python & java соответствующий метод называется `setUp()`, наверное и в Codeception должно быть что-то такое же. Или нужно хранить их безопасно, шифровать как-нибудь?

Comment: Вот пример конфига для базы данных. http://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests

Comment: @NickVolynkin, понятно, что я могу ручками читать любые конфиги (ведь тестовые сценарии - суть программы), просто у меня была надежда, что есть какой-то простой способ взаимодействия с конфигом самого Codeception

Comment: А вот эти .yml это не конфиги самого Codeception?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, это его конфиги. Но я так и не понял, как в нем хранить произвольные параметры и подгружать их в сценарий средствами _самого тестового фреймворка_.

Comment: У меня была надежда, что можно просто понаписать своих переменных в нужное место конфига и они будут доступны во время выполнения. Это тоже не то? )http://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers#Dynamic-Configuration-With-Params

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не похоже. Да вы не переживайте, когда кончится конкурс я придумаю и напишу развернутый ответ ;)

Comment: В целом такие штуки принято выводить в константы классов. Знаю, что это не конфиг, но обще принятый подход такой. Ну и само действие авторизации стоит вынести в хелпер, чтобы вместо `->login` вызывать `->authorize` и не волноваться о внутренностях.

Comment: @Etki, я хочу вынести эти конфигурационные параметры из кода по двум причинам: конфиденциальная информация в репозитории - зло; есть несколько тестовых окружений где выполняются тесты (с разными значениями пары логин/пароль). Про вынесение логики авторизации в хелпер - знаю, специально не стал усложнять код в вопросе.

Comment: * вместо портянки fillField, filleField и вот этого всего, конечно

Comment: @DmitriySimushev если у вас тестовый стенд хранит состояние (имеет постоянных пользователей), то это мягко говоря непредвиденная ситуация. Если вам нужны смоук-тесты c авторизацией, то, возможно, получится вытянуть содeржимое codeception.yml через класс Codeception\Config. В крайнем случае вам остается написать собственный Extension и пробрасывать значения из codeception.yml так или использовать собственную систему конфигурации. В общем, для полного ответа нужно больше информации о том, что это за кейс.

Comment: @Etki, так весь вопрос и сводится к тому, _как_ подгружать параметры из конфигов Codeception в тестовый сценарий :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev вы же хотели вынести параметры из репозитория, нет? Потому что при случае с конфигом они останутся все равно внутри.

Comment: @Etki, нет, вы не правы. Конфиг Codeception позволяет импортировать другие, произвольные конфиги. Как впрочем и значения из переменных окружения. Другой момент, что я не вижу простого способа (из коробки) использовать этот конфиг в своем сценарии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует специальный модуль ([justblackbird/codeception-config-module](https://github.com/JustBlackBird/codeception-config-module)), который позволяет определять произвольные параметры в конфигурационном файле самого Codeception (например в `acceptance.suite.yml`) и использовать их в тестовых сценариях.

Приведу пример использования этого модуля.

**acceptance.suite.yml**:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Config:
            login: '<login>'
            password: '<password>'
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: 'https://example.com/'
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

**LoginCept.php**:

```
<?php

$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->amOnPage('/login');
$I->fillField('Login', $I->grabFromConfig('login'))
$I->fillField('Password', $I->grabFromConfig('password'));
$I->click('Login');
$I->see('You are now logged in!');
```

**Замечание:**

Может показаться, что данное решение позволяет хранить собственные параметры **только** в конфиге Codeception, но это не так. Codeception "из коробки" умеет импортировать сторонние конфигурационные файлы (.yml, .env, .ini) и даже переменные окружения чтобы использовать их в качестве переменных в своем конфигурационном файле. Подробнее об этой возможности можно почитать в [документации](http://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers#Dynamic-Configuration-With-Params).

Comment: по иронии судьбы потребовалось заняться примерно тем же самым (передавать урл приложения, это не произвольный конфиг, как здесь, но все равно), спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Такой конфиг есть. Он называется `_bootstrap.php` и может находиться в каталоге набора тестов, так и в общем каталоге для всех тестов (т.е. в `tests/acceptance/_bootstrap.php` или в `tests/_bootstrap.php`.

Этот файл выполняется перед всеми тестами, а значит всё, определенное в нём, будет видно в самих тестах:

```
<?php // файл _bootstrap.php
$login = 'me@example.com';
$password = 'secret';
```

И тест:

```
$I->fillField('Login', $login)
$I->fillField('Password', $password);
```

[Об этом файле в документации.](http://codeception.com/docs/02-GettingStarted#bootstrap)

В этом файле вы можете не просто задать какие-то константы, но и делать практически все что угодно. Например, получить реквизиты из какого-то другого файла или программы, специфичных для окружения или не отслеживаемых в VCS из соображения конфиденциальности.

Comment: Мне не очень нравится идея добавлять какие-то конфигурационные параметры в файл с кодом, который по-хорошему должен быть в репозитории. Причины тому две: тесты могут выполняться в различных окружениях (с разными наборами логин/пароль) и важная (конфиденциальная) информация по определению не должна попадать в основной репозиторий с кодом.

Comment: Но в целом, использование `_bootstrap.php` - это вариант решения проблемы :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev  Это ж обычный скрипт. В нем можно делать что угодно. Дополнил ответ.